# Can't show div layer in page the function called and while the function is calculating and while page showing items with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a calculator function , this is a big function, when i click the submit button then the calculator function called, no ajax in the function, only client scripts, but lost about 10 seconds to done. The calculator function will calculate and add more objects to $scope.datalist, datalist will be showed in the page by using ng-repeat. My problem is the showloadingpage function don't work right way, i put showloadingpage function at the fist of calculator function because i want show the div layer (with loading page text and gif image)  before run calculator function , but it only show the div layer after the page loaded done. While page loading i can't scroll page or touch elements, all stopped in about 10 seconds.

If i put a return command after $scope.showloadingpage() then div layer will be showed immedialty.

If i remove ng-repeat of datalist then page will load rapid, not stop page and no need div layer of loading status. But alway need ng-repeat to show data in datalist.

```
$scope.calculator = function(){
  $scope.showloadingpage()
  // return;
  // if i put a return command here then div layer will be showed immedialty
  ....
  ....
  ....
  ....
  var i = 0;
  while(++i < 1000){
    ....
    ....
    var object = {.....}
    ....
    ....
    $scope.datalist.push( object );
  }
  // datalist with more 500 objects will be showed in page automatically with ng-repeat.
}

$scope.showloadingpage = function(){
   // <div id="loader-wrapper"></div>
   if (angular.element(document).find('#loader-wrapper').hasClass('hideloading')) {
   angular.element(document).find('#loader-wrapper').removeClass('hideloading');
   angular.element(document).find('#loader-wrapper').addClass('showloading');
}
```

Comment: Please use $scope.showloadingpage() instead of calling showloadingPage() directly.

Comment: yes, thanks, it is right in my code, showloading function called and showed div layer, i only copied short code, easy for everybody to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button ng-click="showloadingpage();calculator();"> Calculate </button>
```

Try this one. This might fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Angular uses jqLite to manipulate DOM elements by default and it's .find() method support tag lookups only. See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element)

BTW, it's not an angular way to modify DOM through addClass or removeClass. You can use ng-show or ng-class directives instead:

```
$scope.calculator = function() {
    $scope.pageIsLoading = true
    .....
    $scope.pageIsLoading = false
}
```

And in your HTML:

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" ng-show="pageIsLoading"></div>
```

Or

```
<div id="loader-wrapper" ng-class="{showloading: pageIsLoading, hideloading: !pageIsLoading}"></div>
```

And finally, you can wrap your heavy function in setTimeout() and calc  it gradually to avoid freezing:

```
function heavyFunction(start, end)
    while(++start < end) {
        var object = {.....}
        $scope.datalist.push( object );
    }
}
```

And then

```
var end = 1000
var step = 100
for (var i = 0; i < end; i+=step) {
     $timeout( //Angular's setTimeout wrapper, should be injected
        (function(start, end) {return heavyFunction.bind(this, start, end)})(i, i + step),
        100
     )
}
```

Or something like that. Hope it helps.

Comment: I have tried your solution, failed.
`
$scope.calculator = function() {
    $scope.pageIsLoading = true
    $timeout(function () {
        // put code here.
    }, 10000);
    $scope.pageIsLoading = false
}
`

Comment: You should set  `$scope.pageIsLoading = false` as last operation inside timeout. Because timeout is an async function, and it will be evaluated after setting pageIsLoading back to false in comment above.